# Shift array elements by n posisition

Tags: java, arrays

I've got `method` to move elements in `array`, move to right work fine, move to left work incorrect. Method get two incoming parameters:

1st: `array`

2nd: `int` variable to move element on this `int` parameter.

Here is my method:

```
private static int[] arrShift(int[]arr, int count) {
    if (count >= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int temp = arr[arr.length - 1];
            for (int j = arr.length - 2; j > -1; j--) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }
            arr[0] = temp;
        }
    }
    if (count < 0){
        count *=-1;
        int temp = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length -1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
        }
        arr[0] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

How shift elements to left?

Comment: You forgot to use the value of `temp` in your second `if`.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work like a charm :)

```
private static int[] arrShift(int[]arr, int count) {
    if (count >= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int temp = arr[arr.length - 1];
            for (int j = arr.length - 2; j > -1; j--) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }
            arr[0] = temp;
        }
    }
    if (count < 0){
        count *=-1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int temp = arr[0];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length -1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            arr[arr.length - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: yes, work fine.